# org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-4

I found a simple problem and ask for help.
There are the exception message:
    Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [factory] for bean with name 'us' defined in class path resource [beans.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: factory

here is interface:
    package net.runze.spr1.factory;

```
public interface Person {
    public void testBeing();
}
```

here is class cn

```
package net.runze.spr1.factory;

public class CN implements Person {

    @Override
    public void testBeing() {
        System.out.println("china");
    }

}
```

here is class us:

```
package net.runze.spr1.factory;

public class US implements Person {

    @Override
    public void testBeing() {
        System.out.println("lalalala US");
    }

}
```

here is the factory:

```
package net.runze.spr1.factory;

public class PersonFactory {
    public Person getPerson(String arg) {
        if ("cn".equalsIgnoreCase(arg)) {
             return new CN();
        } else {
             return new US();
        }
    }
}
```

here is my xml

```
<bean id="factory" class="net.runze.spr1.factory.PersonFactory"/>

<bean id="cn" 
        factory-bean="factory" 
        factory-method="getPerson">
    <constructor-arg value="cn"></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="us" 
        class="factory" 
        factory-method="getPerson">
    <constructor-arg value="us"></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

here is my test class:

```
@Test
public void instanceFactorytest1() {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");

    Person b1 = context.getBean("cn", US.class);
    Person b2 = context.getBean("us", US.class);

    b1.testBeing();
    b2.testBeing();
}
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now i know. really silly~~
i configed it wrong in the xml file

```
<bean id="us"...> this should be "factory-bean" not class.
```